# Trying to save Custom Array of Objects Android

Tags: java, android

So I'm making a notepad application that logs date entered, a subject, and a body text field. When I hit my post button, everything appears properly in my ListView, but when I close the application and re-open it, only the date remains intact and the other two values are NULL. Below is the code I'm using.

```
public class LogList implements Serializable {
private String logDate;
private String logBody;
private String logSubject;

public LogList(String date, String LogBody, String LogSubject){
    super();
    this.logDate = date;
    this.logBody = logBody;
    this.logSubject = logSubject;
}
```

Back in my main class, I have my method that is supposed to save the three values into an ArrayList lts.

```
private void saveInFile(String subject_text, String date, String body_text ){
    LogList lt = new LogList(date, subject_text, body_text);

    lts.add(lt);

    saveAllLogs();
}
```

Now if I change the order of the values in my new LogList, only the first one will be properly displayed after I close my app and reopen it. The following are my saveAllLogs method and my loadFromFile method.

```
private ArrayList<String> loadFromFile(){
    ArrayList<String> logs = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        while (true) {
            LogList lt = (LogList) ois.readObject();
            logs.add(lt.toString());
            lts.add(lt);
        }
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    return logs;
}

private void saveAllLogs() {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, 0);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        for (LogList lti : lts) {
            oos.writeObject(lti);
        }
        fos.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "date" is correct.  Parameters LogBody and LogSubject are never used, because the case of your variables ("logBody") is different from the case of the parameter ("LogBody").

Comment: I hate that such a small mistake has cost me hours trying to fix. Thanks for the help! Switched the variables and it now works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing,

```
public LogList(String date, String LogBody, String LogSubject){
    super();
    this.logDate = date;
    this.logBody = logBody;
    this.logSubject = logSubject;
}
```

Seems wrong. As you have capitalized argument names, but you're setting the members with lowercase names.

Do you mean:

```
public LogList(String date, String logBody, String logSubject){
    super();
    this.logDate = date;
    this.logBody = logBody;
    this.logSubject = logSubject;
}
```

EDIT: Trivial thing, not impacting your code: You don't need your call to `super()` in your constructor as you're not extending any class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I switched the variables and it now works properly.